# add validation in jquery datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({

            minDate: 0,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate)
            }
        });

        $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
            }
        });
    });
```

i have 2 textboxes(with jquery datepicker) which is datepicker1 and datepicker2 and a Search Button. If i click the button with out picking any dates, i want to show up a label that says "please pick a date" is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use [RequiredFieldValidator](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/required-field-validator/) to check for empty input fields.

Also refer to:

[RequiredFieldValidator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)

Comment: RequiredFieldValidator does not support textbox with jquery datepicker. :((

Comment: Yes it does as long as it is a ASP.NET TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

well if you only want to validate against empty textbox then you could just go

Lets say your asp button has an id of "btnSubmit" hence you do this..

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
if (!valdateForm) {
e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the button to submit so you can display error messages or do any other stuff you want. if validateForm returns true, then the form will submit as expected.
}


});

function validateForm() {
    if ($('#datepicker1').val().length == 0 || $('#datepicker2').val().length == 0) {
     return false;
    } else {return true;}
}
```

Comment: but i have a search button. how to connect this with ASP button?

Comment: @JakerusselPalma I've edited my answer but did not test it.. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

sure !

You can either use a plugin that does this for you. jQuery validation is a great pick http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

Or you could write it youself:

```
$("#search").click(function(e){
  if($("#datepicker2").val() === '' ||  $("#datepicker1").val() === ''){
    alert("Please provide a value for date");
    e.cancel();
  }
});
```

Code not tested, you might need to tweak it a bit :)

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnSearchRooms" runat="server" Text="Search Rooms" 
        onclick="btnSearchRooms_Click" /> this is my button. how can i connect it to javascript?

Comment: if you're using an aspnet button, you need to add the clientid:


$("#<%=btnSearchRooms.ClientID %>").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if($("#datepicker2").val() === '' ||  $("#datepicker1").val() === ''){
    alert("Please provide a value for date");
    e.cancel();
  }
});